# The target-entity cannot be found

Tags: entity-framework, symfony

I know this question has already been asked more than once, but I still can't figure what goes wrong.

I'm currently trying to learn Symfony2 (using version 2.7.4), and I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to reach a page that's supposed to have an image in it :

> The target-entity Entity\Image cannot be found in 'OC\PlatformBundle\Entity\Advert#Image'.

Here is my code:

```
**advert.php**

<?php

namespace OC\PlatformBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="OC\PlatformBundle\Entity\AdvertRepository")
 */
class Advert
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
* @ORM\Column(name="published", type="boolean")
*/
private $published = true;

/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Entity\Image", cascade={"persist"})
*/
  private $image;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
 */
private $date;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $author;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
 */
private $content;

/**
 * Set image
 *
 * @param \OC\PlatformBundle\Entity\Image $image
 *
 * @return Advert
 */
public function setImage(\OC\PlatformBundle\Entity\Image $image = null)
{
    $this->image = $image;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get Image
 *
 * @return \OC\PlatformBundle\Entity\Image
 */
public function getImage()
{
    return $this->Image;
}


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function __construct()
{
    // Par défaut, la date de l'annonce est la date d'aujourd'hui
    $this->date = new \Datetime();
}

/**
 * Set date
 *
 * @param \DateTime $date
 *
 * @return Advert
 */
public function setDate($date)
{
    $this->date = $date;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get date
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDate()
{
    return $this->date;
}

/**
 * Set title
 *
 * @param string $title
 *
 * @return Advert
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get title
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

/**
 * Set author
 *
 * @param string $author
 *
 * @return Advert
 */
public function setAuthor($author)
{
    $this->author = $author;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get author
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAuthor()
{
    return $this->author;
}

/**
 * Set content
 *
 * @param string $content
 *
 * @return Advert
 */
public function setContent($content)
{
    $this->content = $content;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get content
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}

/**
 * Set published
 *
 * @param boolean $published
 *
 * @return Advert
 */
public function setPublished($published)
{
    $this->published = $published;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get published
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getPublished()
{
    return $this->published;
}
}
```

file **Image** :

```
<?php
// src/OC/PlatformBundle/Entity/Image

namespace OC\PlatformBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Image
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=255)
   */
  private $url;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(name="alt", type="string", length=255)
   */
  private $alt;
}
```

I understood that this problem mainly comes from a typo in the call of the entity, but I triple-checked everything, and it seems alright to me... Is there something I didn't see ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I assume, after applying @Ziumin's solution, you get the following messages: `The target-entity OC\PlatformBundle\Entity\Image cannot be found in 'OC\PlatformBundle\Entity\Advert#Image'.`... is that correct?

Comment: I think changing   return $this->Image; to   return $this->image; may solve it

Comment: Jason > didn't work, i still have the same error message even after clearing the cache
Jovan > yes, exactly

Comment: Any files under Resources/config/doctrine?

Answer (score 2):

You should fix your annotation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="OC\PlatformBundle\Entity\Image", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $image;
```

Comment: Fixed, but still getting the same mistake, with advert#image instead of advert#Image

Comment: Have you dropped a cache?